# what is python doing with systemtap?

Tags: python, systemtap

I noticed on CentOS-7 distro that the python-2 and python-3 RPM installs both have some "systemtap" scripts installed at `/usr/share/systemtap`.

**What is python doing with `systemtap` scripts?**

I read a little about what is `systemtap` and the description[1] I read sounds like to me that `systemtap` is a kernel debugging/instrumentation tool.

[1] from the [stackoverflow.com tag description:](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/systemtap/info)

> Systemtap is tool to probe or trace a running linux system,
>   supporting visibility into both kernel- (its initial focus)   and
>   user-space.   It uses dynamically loaded probes to gather performance 
>   and tracing data about the whole system or just selected processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemTap can inspect python. Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/instrumentation.html

So the scripts you see in /usr/share/systemtap may include some helper functions for SystemTap to trace python code.